# How do you completely remove ubuntu-desktop along with all installed packages with it?

Tags: 14.04, server

How do you completely remove ubuntu-desktop along with all installed packages with it? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 server on vps and used sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop to install.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even better than just doing remove, you can use purge and then autoremove.

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Purge option according to the man page for apt-get:

```
**purge**
purge is identical to remove except that packages are
removed and purged (any configuration files are deleted too).
```

Answer (score 10):

First do

```bash
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then do the

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus nautilus-* gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-termina* gnome-pane* gnome-applet* gnome-bluetooth gnome-desktop* gnome-sessio* gnome-user* gnome-shell-common zeitgeist-core libzeitgeist* gnome-control-center gnome-screenshot && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

to end up with a completely GUI'less environment. This worked for me to remove the ubuntu-desktop I had installed on my Ubuntu Server

Answer (score 3):

Remove the package and the auto-remove the installed dependencies.  As `root`:

```
apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
```

See also [`apt-get(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) manual page for the `autoremove` argument.

> **autoremove** (and the **auto-remove** alias since 1.1)
>
> > autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get -y purge x11*
sudo apt-get autoremove -y && sudo apt-get autoclean -y
```

This will make sure that any gui based application will also be deleted (web browsers etc)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu:
`sudo apt-get --purge remove libgtk-3-common`

Kubuntu:
`sudo apt-get --purge remove libqtcore4 libkdecore5 kdelibs-bin`

Lubuntu (Version <= 18.04):
`sudo apt-get --purge remove libgtk2.0-0`

Xubuntu:
`sudo apt-get --purge remove libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-common`

Answer (score 0):

Little [script](https://pastebin.com/v5v2U0z0) of mine:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install sed -y
##############UWAGA#################

#potrzebne jest dodatkowe utworzenie dwóch plików:
#usun.txt - gdzie po spacjach wpisujemy paczki do usunięcia - skrypt sam zajmie się usunięciem zależności
#instaluj.txt - gdzie po spacjach wpisujemy paczki do zainstalowania (obligatoryjny jeżeli po reboocie nie chcemy zastać czarnego, zimnego tty ;p)

#aptitude sam rozwiązuje zależności między usuwanymi a instalowanymi paczkami
#nie odpowiadam za ew. szkody ;p
#nie ma za co ;)

usun=`cat usun.txt`
chuj=`apt-cache depends $usun | sed -e 's/.*\ //g' | tr '\r\n' ' '`
instaluj=`cat instaluj.txt`
for i in $instaluj
do
inst=$inst"$i+ "
done
sudo apt-get install aptitude -y
sudo aptitude remove $usun $chuj $inst -y && sudo apt-get autoremove -y && sudo reboot
```

You have to make 2 additional files:

1. usun.txt - that should contain metas (like ubuntu-desktop) separated with spaces you want dependencies to get rid of.
2. instaluj.txt - metas you want to install/keep installed. That would be obligatory if you don't want to see deep, black tty after reboot. Otherwise I'm not responsible for damages.